# Bootstrap Footer in main content but full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay I do not know wether I have started completely wrong or just do not know how to get it right.

I want the layout of my website to be like this:
[image]

I put a div called 'myWrap' around the header and the content. And added this css:

```
.myWrap {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: white;
    top: 2%;
    left: 2%;
    right: 2%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    background: #363130;
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

And the footer is not in the myWrap-div. But now it is just floating behind the content because the position of the myWrap is absolute. 
How do I put the header and content in the normal flow but infront of the background?

I structured the html like that:

```
<div class="row container-fluid myWrap">
    CONTENT
    <div class="container-fluid footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

If I put the footer out of the myWrap div it starts floating around on the top or just overlaps the content/header

Comment: put ```bottom: 0;``` to your class ```.footer``` and you footer is still in the the ```myWrap``` class.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.myWrap` to `position: relative`, your footer is getting the position absolute of the body, because It dosn't have a parent element with a relative position CSS atribute.

```
 .myWrap {
     position: relative;
 }
```

With this, you will get your footer always on the bottom of myWrap. Then you can play with, the top/bottom properties and place it where you want ;)

I have created a Bootply to show it how it's working: http://www.bootply.com/8Wmx3CJHFv

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="myWrap">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
```

Then add your footer after the end of the container

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not work with your own wrapper. Bootstrap made them with a reason and that reason is they will work perfectly for responsive viewports.

I'd suggest you enhance something like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <body>
       <header>
           <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      // content here
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>    
       </header>
       <section id="content">
           <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      // content here
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>    
       </section>
       <footer>
           <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      // content here
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>    
       </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {background-color: #FFF;}
footer {background-color: #FFF;}
header {background-color: #FFF;}
.container-fluid {padding: 0 0;}
```

Just make sure you remove the padding for the .container-fluid. And a tip: if you ever feel like creating your own wrapper, don't position them with absolute, but with relative. Otherwise it won't work well on all viewports.

Comment: But how do I achieve the spacing between the content and the background with that?

Comment: I used max-width:1150px, For testing check this fiddle in above 1150px or change the max-width

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using bootstrap, in bootstrap the container class wraps your data into a wrapper that has a fixed width on each screen-device-width so you will need to add a container div for the header and the content without adding it inside the footer div.
If you are using bootstrap framework you will need to use these following       classes for these div's as the following code:

```
<div class="site-container">
  <div class="header">
     <div class="container">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <div class="container">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
body{
  background:url(../image.jpg);
}
header {
    max-width:600px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background:#ccc;
    height:250px; //header height no need to mention in your work
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:auto;
}
#content {
    max-width:600px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background:#ddd;
    height:500px; //content height no need to mention in your work
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:auto;
}

footer {
    width:100%;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0;
    background:#000;
}
</style>       
<header>
           <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      // Header
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>    
       </header>
       <section id="content">
           <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      // Content
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>    
       </section>
       <footer>
           <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      // content here
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>    
       </footer>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q4Lcjmsy/3/

Comment: 1. Max-width is break point for larger screens. in general it should be above 980px and upto 1366px or max.

Comment: 2.  margin:auto; places a key role for centering header and content in larger screens

Comment: 3. If you want top margin, then change margin:auto; to margin:20px auto 0 auto; in header css

Comment: 4. If you want space above footer then add margin-top:20px; to footer